# commit command after n updates

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, plsql, cursor

I would like to update , let say 1 lack of data and also to run it in a loop with commit for every  10k records of update.
below is the code I tried:

```
DECLARE 
    COUNTER NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN 

    FOR COUNTER IN 1..6 LOOP
    UPDATE table1 t1
        SET EXIST = case 
            when roll_number in (select t2.roll_number from table2 t2 where t1.roll_number=t2.roll_number)
              then 'Y'
                else 'N'
                  end;

    IF (MOD(COUNTER, 2)) = 0
    THEN 
        COMMIT;
    END IF ;
    COUNTER := COUNTER + 1;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

and getting error

```
pls-00363:counter can't be used as an assignment target
```

Comment: SO is for specific questions, not to write code. Please do some search, try something and then, if you have an issue with your code, post a question here

Comment: I have updated my query , can you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Loop variables are automatically created (and cannot be written to).

So the code would look like this

```
BEGIN 
    FOR i IN 1..6 LOOP
      UPDATE table1 t1
          SET EXIST = case 
              when roll_number in (select t2.roll_number from table2 t2 where t1.roll_number=t2.roll_number)
                then 'Y'
                  else 'N'
                    end;

      IF (MOD(i, 2)) = 0
      THEN 
          COMMIT;
      END IF ;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

But let me state very clearly ....

Don't do commits every "n" updates.

Bad bad bad idea.  Increased risk of data corruption, slower performance, way more complex code.

Just a bad idea.